# Xcode 8 Beta - Storyboard ViewController Doesn't Appear the Same in Simulator Using Constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios-simulator, xcode8

I am building a project using ***Xcode 8 Beta***. Here is what my storyboard looks like:

[image: Storyboard]

I have these constraints:

[image: Constraints]

However, my ViewController looks like this in the Simulator:

[image: Simulator]

Comment: If you have a real device, you should test on it.

Comment: Bugs in beta software should be reported to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try it as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue between Xcode and iOS. There is already a bug tracking this. Please try again with subsequent betas.